# Anaconda Navigator Update issue

Tags: anaconda

Would anyone know how to get Anaconda Navigator to update to the latest version of 2.1.0?  Every time I try it will not do it. I looked it up on Youtube and there was a video post that said to try as an administrator.  I tried that as well.  When I hit update the window opens and strongly suggests updating to 2.1.0.  It asks me if I want to update it, and I tap the yes button in green.  It says that it will automatically shut down and begin the update, but once it shuts down it never updates or anything.  Can anyone give me some insight as to what to do next?

Answer (score 1):

Same issue, Solved by opening command prompt as administrator and using

**conda install anaconda-navigator=2.2.0**